# Set selected option when select elements dynamically generated ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, drop-down-menu, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to dynamically generate select elements based on an array:

```
[
  ["Air travel program","Yes",[["--"],["Yes"],["No"]]],
  ["Car rental program","--",[["--"],["Yes"],["No"]]],
  ["Data management","--",[["--"],["Yes"],["No"]]],
  ["Group travel","--",[["--"],["Yes"],["No"]]],
  ["Hotel Program","--",[["--"],["Yes"],["No"]]],
  ["Payment systems","--",[["--"],["Yes"],["No"]]],
  ["Transient travel","--",[["--"],["Yes"],["No"]]],
  ["Travel policy","No",[["--"],["Yes"],["No"]]]
]
```

My HTML:

```
<div class="profileRow"  ng-repeat="btpPDropdown in BTPProfileSelectList">
                    <label class="profileLabel">
                                            {{btpPDropdown[0]}}
                    </label>
                    <select name="{{btpPDropdown[0]}}" >
                                            <option ng-repeat="btpOption in btpPDropdown[2]">{{btpOption[0]}}</option>
                    </select>
```

This generates the select elements and options as expected but I cannot figure out how to set the default selected option, which should be {{btpPDropdown[1]}}, or Yes in the first select.
As I understand it, the select will set the selected option to a matching option string. I tried setting ng-model="{{btpPDropdown[1]}}" but this is invalid as it wouldn't be unique.
Any help to get this to work would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you rephrase the question? Are you saying the options aren't showing up, or are you having a problem referencing the ng-model?

Comment: The options are showing up. I just can't figure out how to set the default selected option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with what you had was that you weren't binding the select to a model. Providing the model on the select itself allows you to bind it to the array. This way, when changing a drop down it will reflect in the actual array.

Modified code below:

```
<div class="profileRow"  ng-repeat="btpPDropdown in BTPProfileSelectList">
    <label class="profileLabel">
      {{btpPDropdown[0]}}
    </label>
    <select name="{{btpPDropdown[0]}}" ng-model="btpPDropdown[1]">
      <option ng-repeat="btpOption in btpPDropdown[2]" >{{btpOption[0]}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome! I see what I was doing wrong when I WAS trying to provide the model. I was using {{btpPDropdown[1]}}

Comment: Yeah I've definitely done that before. All of those provided Angular 'ng-' directives treat everything between the quotes as an Angular expression, so there is no need for the braces.